# Python is printing when it should not print, and printing what should not print

Tags: python

---

```
animals = [('dog','Fort','brown'), ('dog', 'Nutmeg', 'brown'), ('cat', 'Oreo', 'black'), ('cat','Tiger','brown'), ('dog', 'Taco', 'white'), ('cat', 'Menoly', 'calico')]

for animal in animals: 
    print(animal[1] + ' is a ' + animal[2] + " " + animal[0])

color = input("Please choose one of the above colors: ").lower() 

for animal in animals:
    if color in animal[2]:
        print(animal[1] + ' is ' + color)
    else:
        print('No pets are ' + color)
        break
```

---

**Output should be:**
Fort is brown
Nutmeg is brown
Tiger is brown

**Why is it printing out?:**
Fort is brown
Nutmeg is brown
No pets are brown

Comment: You probably want `if color == animal[2]` rather than `if color in animal[2]`

Comment: More generally, try the [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) guide?

Comment: Your loop basically breaks out when it doesn't find it color due to ```break```

Comment: You also should be testing `if color not in [a[2] for a in animals]`

Comment: Consider checking out python loops tutorial again

Answer (score 0):

In your code, if the condition is not True, it breaks.

```
if color == animal[2]:  #==== Use == instead of in
        print(animal[1] + ' is ' + color) 
    else:
        print('No pets are ' + color) #===== Printing this
        break #====== Break. Because the condition: color==animal[2] were not met and break broke out of the loop
```

You can use list comprehension and check if the list is empty or not.

```
color = input("Please choose one of the above colors: ").lower() 
x=[animal[1]+" is "+color for animal in animals if color==animal[2]]
if x==[]:
    print('No pets are ' + color)
else:
    for j in x:
        print(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop prints "No pets are ..." too early.

Logically, it should wait to print that message after *all* pets have been processed and no matches were found.  Instead, it prints that message when the *current* pet does not match.